# how can I know what tables queried in my select sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get whole table names from an existing selecting sql. 
for example.my select sql is

```
select * from hello h .
```

how can I get what tables queried in the sql? 
you can only add extra str connecting the select sql, like "explain".
[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for. But as far as I could understand you can get the role name of the tables removing the ALIAS. E.g. instead "products p" use just "products". It is is not what you looking for, let me know.

Comment: I *suppose* you could use a regex to find the alias from the table, then regex the original SQL query to find the table names.

Comment: yes, I want to get proudcts ,not p. but I can not change the sql removing the "p" , some sql is provide by other people

Comment: so can only do the job in php using regex?

Comment: I assume that you were just testing your query, why don't you condition it on your front end. If its p return or echo products and do same in pd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *want* to get is not possible unless it is offered from the Software you use.

According to the Mysql-Issue-Tracker, that feature you're looking for *is not* available:

- [Bug #24693- explain output should provide un-aliased table names](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24693)

I suggest you read through that ticket as it has some comments with suggestions that might help you to better understand your issue.

So the answer to your question is that you until now need to keep a reference your own which alias belongs to which table. Which for the SQL query you have in your example looks rather straight forward to me.

Comment: real real good answer , thank you very much